# how users will to get ubuntu for phones?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm pantech's vega r3 user. This phone matches to highend spec for ubuntu for phone. How you will provide for android phone like this? 
Cwm or recovery installable package? Or through OEM or Carrier OTA?
I wish more fastly come ubuntu on my phone. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should keep in mind that Ubuntu Touch is still very buggy and crashes alot when installed.

Comment: ...not to mention, Ubuntu Touch may never work on your particular phone.

Comment: Hey thanks friends. But I know ubuntu is not perfect now. Just my question is about canonical's response in future.

Comment: Canonical's officially said "ubuntu touch will installable on most android device." My knowledge is not right?